# Exponential to decimal java android

Tags: java, android, math, decimal, exponential

I have a trouble, i'm doing calculators for school and i need to convert "E" to decimal in answer.

**I have: 6.67E-11**

**I want: 6.67 * 10^-11**

```
double m1 = Double.parseDouble(et1.getText().toString());
double m2 = Double.parseDouble(et2.getText().toString());
double R = Double.parseDouble(et3.getText().toString());

double answer = (6.67 * Math.pow(10, -11)) * ((m1 * m2) / sqrt(R));

tv_answer.setText(answer + "");
```

I can add this:

```
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("###.####################");
String f = formatter.format(answer);
```

and edit:

```
tv_answer.setText(f + "");
```

But i will get something like this: **0.0000000000667**. That's not cool :/

Comment: use BigDecimal double have troubleshoot in calculating

Comment: As @crammeur, you really ought to use BigDecimals here or you'll get rounding issues.  But ifnoring that-  its doing exactly what you told it to do-  formatting the number as a serious of digits.  What you want isn't really built into DecimalFormat, because nobody actually uses the long format like that.  If you want it, you're going to have to write it yourself.  Although I'd question why E isn't sufficient, its well understood notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the best way, but you can try this.

```
    BigDecimal d1 = new BigDecimal("0.0000000000000096");
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.0E0");
    System.out.print(df.format(d1).replace("E"," * 10^"));
```

Output

> 9.6 * 10^-15

Comment: Perfect answer.

Answer (score 1):

**BigDecimal Example**

```
double m1 = Double.parseDouble(et1.getText().toString());
double m2 = Double.parseDouble(et2.getText().toString());
double R = Double.parseDouble(et3.getText().toString());

double answer = BigDecimal.valueOf(6.67)
            .multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(Math.pow(10,-11)))
            .multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(m1).multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(m2).divide(Math.sqrt(R),21,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP)))
            .doubleValue();

tv_answer.setText(answer + "");
```